# Enabling full-text search facility on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have SQL Server 2008 installed on my computer along with the full-text search facility. The problem is that full-text search is not running. When I go to SQL Server services in Computer Management I find that 'SQL full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (MSSQLSERVER)' is stopped with the start mode: Other(Boot, System, Disabled or Unknown). If I right click 'Start' is greyed out. What do I do ?

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if you are using an evaluation copy of SQL Server and the evaluation period is over.